# Copying a file from an HD with bad sectors

Tags: data-recovery, copy

I am trying to copy various files from one HD to another.
on some files after several minutes (too many, say 5 minutes for an 11Mb file) I get this error and the file is not copied.

```
cp: error reading 'TRACKS.dat': Input/output error
```

Oddly enough, however, I can read it.

So i checked the log and find these two errors:

```
blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 9319483552 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 128 prio class 0
sd 10:0:0:0: [sde] tag#9 timing out command, waited 180s
```

From what i understand there are bad-sector errors and then the system goes into timeout.
My question is how can i copy the files without waiting so long?